# Can I use yosys in Visual Studio Code with connect to WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, yosys

I'm going to use Yosys to synthesize my IC design project for a subject at school. I have used WSL to code before so I wonder if I can use Yosys without installing Ubuntu to my computer

I have tried to run it but in the last step, it occured an error with the local file of Yosys and I don't know how to fix this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op6iq.png)